# Drupal 7 Domain Access XML Sitemap

Tags: drupal-7, sitemap, drupal-domain-access

What is the best way to accomplish creating sitemaps for a Drupal 7 using domain access.  I can generate the sitemaps using the xml module and domain access.  I cannot however get to the sitemaps through their url.  Any ideas how I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Views data export module to accomplish this.

https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export/issues/2061697

However some small changes in the views template files will be required.